# Deleting Specific Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, delete-operator, worksheet

I am attempting to delete all worksheets in my workbook except for the two titled: "main" and "dataset". My current code seems to simply delete the last two worksheets.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Sub DeleteWS()
    Dim mySheet As String, mySheet2 As String, ws As Worksheet
    mySheet = "main"
    mySheet2 = "Dataset"
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> mySheet Or ws.Name <> mySheet2 Then
           ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
```

to this:

```
ws.Delete
```

to fix your If statement

Use `And` in your `If`, not `Or`

and keep in mind that capitalization and extra spaces both matter too in a comparison like that.

I would use something more like this:

```
If Trim$(UCase$(ws.Name)) <> Trim$(UCase$(mySheet)) And _
Trim$(UCase$(ws.Name)) <> Trim$(UCase$(mySheet2)) Then
```

Comment: I ran it and it deletes all the worksheets in the workbook, my if statement is not working.

Comment: Use AND instead of OR

Comment: Thank you, using AND helped. My code now runs properly:

Answer (score 1):

You could also go like this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Sub DeleteWS()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If InStr(ws.Name, “main,Dataset”) = 0 Then ws. Delete
    Next
End Sub
```